# Does RichFaces 4.0 contain notifyMessages?

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I am following this link to learn about richfaces: http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=notify&sample=notifyMessages&skin=blueSky

But the problem is, when i try rich:notify or rich:notifyMessages, i get an error saying that "The component library http://richfaces.org/rich does not contain component notifyMessages". Can anyone tell me why? I can use other components of richfaces but there is no notify component here.

Thanks

Comment: Make sure you're using RichFaces 4 libraries and not RichFaces 3 or older

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza i am sure about that, can there be any other problem than this one?

Comment: Make sure the RichFaces libraries are well set in WEB-INF/lib folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rich:notify* components where introduce in RichFaces 4.1.
Refer to docs:
http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_0_X/Component_Reference/en-US/html/ (rich:notify is not listed)
http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_1_X/Component_Reference/en-US/html/ (rich:notify is there)